# How do I get the height of a div's full content with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scroll, height

I am trying to create my own scroll bars. I have tried most of the jquery scrollbar plugins and none of them seem to work for me, so I decided to create my own. I have an overflow area with scrollable content. I can get the scrollbar to work if I am able to figure out the height of the scrollable content area. I have tried .scrollHeight() and the browser doesn't even recognize it. The overflow area has a fixed position.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

[`scrollHeight` is a property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollHeight) of a [DOM object](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrollheight), not a function:

> Height of the scroll view of an element; it includes the element padding but not its margin.

Given this:

```
<div id="x" style="height: 100px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="height: 200px;">
        pancakes
    </div>
</div>
```

This yields 200:

```
$('#x')[0].scrollHeight
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/u69kQ/2/ (run with the JavaScript console open).

Comment: Every where I read about scrollHeight, no one ever said that the [0] was needed and that scrollheight is not a function. I'm assuming, after trying this, that I got the correct height. I will not know until I implement the calculations for the scrollbar. But, you get the points. Thanks!

Comment: @mtlca401: You need the `[0]` to extract the underlying DOM object from the jQuery object, that gives you the same sort of thing that `document.getElementById()` will give you. You can also use jQuery's [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get) function.

Comment: I get 4260px in chrome and 4300px in firefox, but I'm assuming this is because of padding maybe? Is this correct?

Comment: @mtlca401: could be a lot of things (margins, paddings, line-height, font rendering differences, ...), ~1% difference isn't that much.

Comment: If you want the actual scrollTop height you will need scrollLength = $('#x')[0].scrollHeight - $('#x').height();

Comment: @Alvaro: Is Opera 12 the old Opera or Opera-Next? What does "not work" mean?

Comment: Well, I mean that it doesn't calculate the content height correctly. If the container has a fixed height with `overflow:scroll`, then it gets the `height` of the container, not of the content. I talk about Opera 12.16, the old version of Opera browser, which still being used by many people. The last version which doesn't include Webkit engine.

Answer (score 33):

If you can possibly help it, **DO NOT USE .scrollHeight**.

.scrollHeight does not yield the same kind of results in different browsers in certain circumstances (most prominently while scrolling).

For example:

```
<div id='outer' style='width:100px; height:350px; overflow-y:hidden;'>
<div style='width:100px; height:150px;'></div>
<div style='width:100px; height:150px;'></div>
<div style='width:100px; height:150px;'></div>
<div style='width:100px; height:150px;'></div>
<div style='width:100px; height:150px;'></div>
<div style='width:100px; height:150px;'></div>
</div>
```

If you do

> console.log($('#outer').scrollHeight);

you'll get 900px in Chrome, FireFox and Opera. That's great.

**But**, if you attach a wheelevent / wheel event to #outer, when you scroll it, Chrome will give you a constant value of 900px (correct) but FireFox and Opera will change their values as you scroll down (incorrect).

A very simple way to do this is like so (a bit of a cheat, really). (This example works while dynamically adding content to #outer as well):

```
$('#outer').css("height", "auto");
var outerContentsHeight = $('#outer').height();
$('#outer').css("height", "350px");

console.log(outerContentsHeight); //Should get 900px in these 3 browsers
```

The reason I pick these three browsers is because all three can disagree on the value of .scrollHeight in certain circumstances. I ran into this issue making my own scrollpanes. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: since scrollHeight is a DOM property, shouldn't you be using `$('#outer').get(0).scrollHeight` instead?

Answer (score 33):

We can also use -

```
$('#x').prop('scrollHeight') <!-- Height -->
$('#x').prop('scrollWidth')  <!-- Width -->
```

Answer (score 5):

`Element.scrollHeight` is a property, not a function, as noted [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534615%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). As noted [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight), the scrollHeight property is only supported after IE8. If you need it to work before that, temporarily set the CSS `overflow` and `height` to `auto`, which will cause the div to take the maximum height it needs. Then get the height, and change the properties back to what they were before.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollHeight says IE 8 is the lowest version it supports, so it would be "after IE7" or "IE8 and later"

Answer (score 2):

You can get it with `.outerHeight()`.

Sometimes, it will return `0`. For the best results, you can call it in your `div`'s ready event.

To be safe, you should not set the height of the `div` to `x`. You can keep its height `auto` to get content populated properly with the correct height.

```
$('#x').ready( function(){
// alerts the height in pixels
alert($('#x').outerHeight());
})
```

You can find a detailed post [here](https://17path.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/how-to-get-height-of-an-element-in-jquery/).

Answer (score 1):

1. Using `scrollHeight` is not only buggy, but doesn't work when your container has a hardcoded height (which is probably most cases, since you wanna get contents height without doing `container.height()` itself)
2. @shazboticus-s-shazbot solution is good when you can mess around with the container height temporarily / have a hard-coded height.
3. An alternative solution would be:

```js
$('#outer')
    // Get children in array format, as we'll be reducing them into a single number
    .contents().toArray()
    // Filter out text and comment nodes, only allowing tags
    .filter(el => el.nodeType === 1)
    // Sum up all the children individual heights
    .reduce((accumulator, el) => $(el).outerHeight(true) + accumulator, 0);
```

Of course, this latter alternative only works when `#outer` doesn't have immediate text childrens that take up space and you want to measure. Those are my 2 cents.

4. If you want to measure unwrapped text, I'd suggest modifying your DOM tree and having an inner `<div>` of which you can measure easily by doing `$('#outer').children().height()`