# jQuery get height of scrolled content inside div

Tags: jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery: how do I get the height of a div’s full content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853293/jquery-how-do-i-get-the-height-of-a-divs-full-content)

Lets say I've got 600px high div, that has scrolling enabled, and I've got a lot of content inside it so it has scrollbar. How to get height of content inside it?

Answer (score 2):

It is called **scrollHeight**. You need to give:

```
$(element).get(0).scrollHeight
```

For eg., to know the scroll height of the total page, you can use:

```
$("body").get(0).scrollHeight
```