# Get auto height of an element without setting height to auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I'd like to get the height of an element, if said element was currently set to `height:auto;`, without actually setting the elements height to auto.

Pretty straight forward, but I can't figure out how to obtain the auto height value without first setting the element's height to auto. That's the part I'm trying to avoid.

Anyone know how I would do this?

---

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxS2H/) will demonstrate my issue.

I'm trying to set all three headings to the same height. When resize the window I need the heights to adjust. With the current script the height is first set to auto, which causes the height to jump around a bit. I'm trying to avoid this jump.

---

I'll try to clarify the jump I'm referring to - When you resize the window, if the heading heights change, the animation to the new height will start. However the animation always resets to it's 'auto' height before the animation starts.

So for example:

1. Auto height = 20px
2. On resize all elements animate from auto height (20px) to new height (ie - 40px)
3. If resized again all elements reset to auto height (20px) THEN animate to another new height (ie - 60px)

So if you consider step 2 to 3, my goal is to have the animation start from the current height (40px) and proceed to the new height (60px), instead of resetting to the auto height (20px) before animating to the new height (60px).

Hopefully this helps even further...

Comment: can you post some html or jsFiddle?

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle link to describe my exact situation better.

Comment: Not sure I understood, but perhaps using the screen-values `vh vw` may help? https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Answer (score 1):

You can take the `scrollHeight` of the element and optionally add top and bottom padding and border depending on the box-sizing property.

You may get into some inconsistencies with different browsers (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15033226/1669279), but if you really want to avoid changing the height property, this is the only way.

Oh, one other idea: you can set the `height` of the parent to `auto` and set the `height` of the element to some `%` value, which will turn the computed value to `auto`. Not sure if that is in the spirit of the question even if you don't literally set the `height` to `auto`.

You can make the following changes in your JsFiddle according to my (first) suggestion:

```
heading.each(function () {
    var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(this);
    var height = this.scrollHeight - parseInt(computedStyle.paddingTop) - parseInt(computedStyle.paddingBottom) - parseInt(computedStyle.borderTop) - parseInt(computedStyle.borderBottom);
    if (height > h) {
        h_elem = this;
        h = height;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tibos. I'm not entirely sure how to test your answer out. I've added a jsfiddle demonstrating my exact situation. Perhaps you can check it out and provide your solution with an example?

Answer (score 0):

"With the current script the height is first set to auto, which causes
the height to jump around a bit. I'm trying to avoid this jump."

---

I don't understand what do you mean when you say "The height jump around", maybe because you animate height without .stop() but here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/Mk9HS/), and bellow you can see the change. If that's the jumping you're talking about...

```
heading.stop().animate({height:h+"px"},200); // Animate with .stop()

// or

heading.css({height:h+"px"},200); // Change height with CSS
```

In latest Chrome looks nice.

Comment: I'll try to clarify - When you resize the window, if the heading heights change, the animation to the new height will start. However the animation always resets to it's 'auto' height before adjusting to the height. This is the 'jump' I'm referring to. I'll make an edit to clarify.