# Jquery scrolls up after messages are sent in chat page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, socket.io

The auto scroll works for a couple messages on it's own. Then it randomly gives out and starts scrolling up when the user sends a message.

Here's the applicable Javascript. And the limited styles (Haven't really gotten to styling yet.) Also, the site if you want a reference as to what it looks like is http://schoolsurvivaltools.com:3000

```
//send message
$messageForm.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val());
    $messageBox.val("");
    $("#chat").animate({ scrollTop: $("#chat").height() }, "fast");
    return false;
});

//Add the users message to the chat.
socket.on('pushMessage', function(data){
    $chat.append("<li><b>" + data.nick+ ": " + "</b>" + data.msg + " </br>" + "</li>");
    $("#chat").animate({ scrollTop: $("#chat").height() }, "fast");
});
```

Styling:

```
#chat {
    height:500px;
    width:300px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
#mainWrap {
    display:none;
}
#chatWrap {
    float: left;
    border:1px #000 solid;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    width:302px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `height` function in jQuery will give you the height of the element, but you want the height of the contents of the element. See here [How do I get the height of a div's full content with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853293/how-do-i-get-the-height-of-a-divs-full-content-with-jquery)

Comment: This is a link to an answer.  Please put the relevant code and documentation here since links can change.  If you feel this question has been answered already, please flag it as such.

Comment: Im still getting the same scroll up issue after a certain number of messages... going to see how many, using this code: Wont run in JSFiddle, but you can see the result in the above link to site in the OP. Here is the code : http://jsfiddle.net/bjuz3bxg/