# JS check if contents overflowing verticaly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to make so do something if its overflowing Verticaly. Lead me towards right direction.

Exmaple:

```css
.contents {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="contents">
CONTENT CCC<br>
CONTENT CCC<br>
CONTENT CCC<br>
CONTENT CCC<br>
CONTENT CCC<br>
CONTENT CCC<br>
CONTENT CCC<br>
CONTENT CCC<br>
<div>


<!-- This would result to do an action. ->
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853293/how-do-i-get-the-height-of-a-divs-full-content-with-jquery) might help.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Checked it allready, it determines the overflow horisontaly not verticaly.

Comment: @Draco18s Yeh it did help. thanks.

Comment: Then, as it says, [edit] your question to include what you've tried before.

Comment: You don't mention that you've seen that question, nor how that question failed to help you. We're looking for an indication that you've done your research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/qq3w1k3a/

If the height is set via CSS, you can check the height specified in the styling against the `scrollHeight`. a.e the following will alert `true` or `false` depending on if the supplied element's scroll height is larger than it's specified size.

```
function check_height(ele) {
  let styleHeight = +getComputedStyle(ele).getPropertyValue('height').slice(0,-2);
  alert(ele.scrollHeight > styleHeight);
}
```

**Edit**: to elaborate on this `+getComputedStyle(ele).getPropertyValue('height').slice(0,-2);`

`getComputedStyle(ele)` is a window method that will, as the name suggests, grab all the styling of the specified element. The returned object has a method called `getPropertyValue` that allows you to specify what property you would like to grab(in this case `height`).

`.slice(0, -2)` is just a normal array method that removes the last two characters of the string. (since strings are just an *array* of characters this works)

the `+` sign in front of all of it is to automatically convert the value to an integer instead of keeping it as a string.

Comment: Yep it work, its almost kinda same as adding another Div and comparing it, like @geuis wrote. but this approach is more swift, gonna go analyse stuff now haha, thanks :)
EDIT: Allright, I understood the approach of it, Im just not familiar with some functions of Js yet, kinda fresh on it. Thanks for the explination aswell!

Comment: Sure thing @T.Lowly - I wrote up an explanation for this as well as other concepts in an article a little while back. https://medium.com/wdstack/27-everyday-javascript-tricks-for-beginner-web-developers-2c04d572dde -- feel free to check it out!

Comment: Thanks, I will definetely read it trough :)

Answer (score 1):

Add an inner wrapper.

```
<div class="contents">
  <div class="inner">
    CONTENT CCC<br>
    CONTENT CCC<br>
    CONTENT CCC<br>
    CONTENT CCC<br>
    CONTENT CCC<br>
    CONTENT CCC<br>
    CONTENT CCC<br>
    CONTENT CCC<br>
  </div>
<div>
```

Then you can get `document.querySelector('.inner').outerHeight` and if its greater than the `.contents` height, you have your answer.

Comment: This is a valid point, though I need to stop it overflowing while doing few other things at it. But thanks! Why I didint even think of trying it.